# Using grepl to search and change data in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a dataframe where one of the columns has data of car sales. I need to create a new column with the grepl function that changes the type of sale from, examples:

```
Loan to L
Free to F
$XXXm to B  (XX are numbers)
-    to F
Loan:XX to S
```

But when I try to create a new column below, it seems like it recognized all the values as `TRUE` and changes the values in the new column to either one of L, F, B, etc etc.

```
dat$carSaletype2<-dat$carSaletype2[grepl("Free",dat[,carSaletype])]<-"F"
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem with `grepl("Free", c("Loan to L", "Free to F"))`  Okay, you are doing double assignment `dat$carSaletype2<-` is not needed

Comment: The values I listed are examples. So the value in the current cell is Free. I need to change it to: F

Comment: Ok, got it.  The problem is in the double assignment

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use `grepl` instead of `gsub`?

Comment: I was suggested to use grepl. But curious to see the solution with gsub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial assignment

```
dat$carSaletype2<-
```

is not needed.  It changes the whole column to the value assigned from

```
dat$carSaletype2[grepl("Free", dat[,carSaletype])] <- "F"
```